# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock in JQuery

Tags: javascript

I wrote a little Javascript [rock/paper/scissors/lizard/spock game](http://codepen.io/imcconnell/pen/zKYgVX) and when the user clicks the button to make their choice from the five options, I choose the computer's randomly  and then compare the two to find a winner and output the result. It works, but I have the feeling that the `findWinner` function can be a lot shorter or more elegant. I'm trying to improve my Javascript and jQuery and was hoping for someone to help me with next steps here:.

```
function findWinner(choiceA,choiceB) {
  if (choiceA == choiceB) {
    return "It's a tie!"; 
  }

  if (choiceA == 'Rock') {
    if (choiceB == 'Lizard' || choiceB == 'Scissors') {
      return "You win!";
    }
    else if (choiceB == 'Spock' || choiceB == 'Paper') {
      return choiceB;
    }
  }
  else if (choiceA == 'Paper') {
    if (choiceB == 'Rock' || choiceB == 'Spock') {
      return "You win!";
    }
    else if (choiceB == 'Scissors' || choiceB == 'Lizard') {
      return "Computer wins :( "; 
    }
  }
  else if (choiceA == 'Scissors') {
    if (choiceB == 'Paper' || choiceB == 'Lizard') {
      return "You win!";
    }
    else if (choiceB == 'Spock' || choiceB == 'Rock') {
      return "Computer wins :( "; 
    }
  }
  else if (choiceA == 'Lizard') {
    if (choiceB == 'Paper' || choiceB == 'Spock') {
      return "You win!";
    }
    else if (choiceB == 'Rock' || choiceB == 'Scissors') {
      return "Computer wins :( "; 
    }
  }
  else if (choiceA == 'Spock') {
    if (choiceB == 'Rock' || choiceB == 'Scissor') {
      return "You win!";
    }
    else if (choiceB == 'Paper' || choiceB == 'Lizard') {
      return "Computer wins :( "; 
    }
  }
}
```

This just seems very repetitive, but I'm not sure where to go next with it.

Answer (score 13):

Write down the rules in an object. If an object contains a key, it means it can beat it.

Also, you're writing a javascript game, not jQuery. jQuery is a javascript library.

```js
var rules = {
  rock: {
    scissors: true,
    lizard: true
  },
  scissors: {
    paper: true,
    lizard: true
  },
  lizard: {
    paper: true,
    spock: true
  },
  spock: {
    rock: true,
    scissors: true
  },
  paper: {
    rock: true,
    spock: true
  }
};

function play(opt1, opt2) {
  if (opt1 === opt2) {
    return "Draw";
  }

  if (rules[opt1][opt2]) {
    return "You win";
  }

  return "You loose";
}

console.log(play("rock", "scissors"));
console.log(play("paper", "paper"));
console.log(play("lizard", "spock"));
```

Comment: It would be better to have the value as an array rather than object. No need for true or false

Comment: With an array you'll have to do an `indexOf` kind of check, with an object it's an instant return. But for an array with only 2 values, there's probably no difference.

Comment: How would `indexOf` not be an instant return?

Comment: What I meant is that `indexOf` loops over the array, which takes more time. With an object, you don't need a loop.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the time difference is marginal at best. Not saying this is a bad answer, the more different aproaches the better

Comment: That's exactly what I ended my first reply with ;)

Comment: I didn't see that part. Excuse my skim reading :)

Comment: @CarlMarkham, but array is object, too.

Comment: @user3297291, with array one can use `Array.prototype.some()`.

Comment: Perhaps instead of this structure: `scissors: { paper: true, lizard: true }` (etc) this would be more use: `scissors: { paper: 'cuts', lizard: 'decapitates' }`

Comment: Agree that using object keys for lookup is best approach here.  The `true` value is not needed as pointed out, but this allows lookup at that should perform ~ twice as fast in worst case than having numerically-indexed array holding the values.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an object. The following function uses the [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function for checking existence of the `choiceB` in the arrays, if the item exists in the array the user wins, otherwise the winner is computer.

```
var items = {
  'Rock': ['Lizard', 'Scissors'],
  'Paper': ['Spock', 'Rock'],
  'Scissors': ['Paper', 'Lizard'],
  'Lizard': ['Paper', 'Spock'],
  'Spock': ['Rock', 'Scissors']
};

function findWinner(choiceA, choiceB) {
  if (choiceA === choiceB) return "It's a tie!";
  return items[choiceA].includes(choiceB) ? 'You win!' : 'Computer wins!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be much shorter!

```js
function game(you, enemy){
  val = function(x){return (parseInt(x,36)%46305)%11;} 
  sum = (val(enemy)-val(you)+5)%5;
  return (sum==0)?"tie":(sum==1||sum==3)?"win":"loss"; 
}
```

How does it work?

[if we look at the wikipedia picture for the game we can see that we have five states, and that the rules are symmetric. Surely, you must see the pattern!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt5q3.png)

- First, we translate the States into coordinates on the pentagram.
- Then, we bruteforce a salt (`parseInt(x,36)%46305)%11;`) that
  translates the human input into workable coordinates (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
- Finally we determine the distance between the coordinates and what it
  means. If they're on the same spot, we have a tie. if they're one or
  three spaces ahead, (going clockwise), you win. Otherwise you lose.

```js
function game(you, enemy){
  val = function(x){return (parseInt(x,36)%46305)%11;} //hash into coordinates
  sum = (val(enemy)-val(you)+5)%5; // determine the distance
  return (sum==0)?"tie":(sum==1||sum==3)?"win":"loss"; // determine the outcome 
}

/*
* TEST
*/

console.log(game("paper","paper"));
console.log(game("paper","rock"));
console.log(game("paper","lizard"));
console.log(game("paper","spock"));
console.log(game("paper","scissors"));
console.log("");
console.log(game("rock","paper"));
console.log(game("rock","rock"));
console.log(game("rock","lizard"));
console.log(game("rock","spock"));
console.log(game("rock","scissors"));
```

A solution like this has the advantage that it will give cheaters a bad time if the rules are supposed to be hidden! (in the general case. here, probably not very important)

EDIT:

While we're at it, I might as well show you a quick and dirty compression, for reference.

```js
num = function(text,s) { return (parseInt(text,36)%s)%11; } //solve for s
crit = function(s) { return num("scissors",s)+ //build target environment
  num("paper",s)*10+
  num("rock",s)*100+
  num("lizard",s)*1000+
  num("spock",s)*10000; }
brut = function(){for(i=1;i<100000;i++){if(crit(i)==54321){return(i);}}}
console.log(brut());
```

History:

If I had come up with this four years earlier, I could have won the The International Obfuscated C Code Contest ;D

It turns out that Adrian Cable came up with an [almost identical method in 2013](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2013_cable1) which won him a spot in the IOCCC then. He even uses the same two stage double modulo method.

Comment: Since you have control over the input, this is overkill, but enormously clever

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a variation on @user3297291's answer that provides the winning mechanism as well as just determining the victor

```js
var rules =
 { rock:     { scissors: 'crushes', lizard: 'crushes'     }
 , paper:    {     rock: 'covers',   spock: 'disproves'   }
 , scissors: {    paper: 'cuts',    lizard: 'decapitates' }
 , lizard:   {    spock: 'poisons',  paper: 'eats'        }
 , spock:    { scissors: 'smashes',   rock: 'vaporizes'   }
 };

var actors = [];
for (var property in rules) {
    rules.hasOwnProperty(property) && actors.push(property);
}

var iterations = 3;
function test() {
 for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var a = b = actors[Math.floor(Math.random() * actors.length)];
  while (b == a) b = actors[Math.floor(Math.random() * actors.length)];
  var winner = rules[a][b]? a : b;
  var loser = winner == a? b : a;
  console.log(winner+" "+rules[winner][loser]+" "+loser);
 }
}

function init() {
 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener( 'click', function() { iterations = parseInt(document.getElementById('iterations').value); test(); }, false );
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```html
<input id="iterations" size="2" value="3">
<button id="button">test</button>
```